# read multiple wav files in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio-processing

I want read multiple wav files one by one in one folder. I wrote this way, but it gives "Invalid Wave File. Reason: Cannot open file." error. But when i change t to number, it works.

```
for t=1:10
    myFile=['path\','t.wav'];
    [ speech, fs] = wavread( myFile);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the variable `t` to a string. You were asking to open the file `'path\t.wav'`, which presumably doesn't exist. Since the variable `t` is an integer, you can use [`int2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int2str.html) to convert it to a string:

```
myFile = ['path\' int2str(t) '.wav'];
```

Only strings can be concatenated with other strings. Of course if you have fewer than 10 files, then you'll have another problem...

Answer (score 0):

you can use the special print f command: sprintf(); to assign myFile this string.

```
myFile = sprintf('path\%d.wav',t);
```

sprintf works in MATLAB just like it does in the C environment.